# Please help identify this Siemens TO-92 NEMOS

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification

[image: Siemens k4 ss 98 N-channel enhancement-mode MOSFET]

This Siemens device, marked "k4 S S 98" is used in place of a [2N4401](https://datasheet.octopart.com/2N4401BU-ON-Semiconductor-datasheet-500104.pdf) NPN.

The 2N4401 NPN is EBC from front, so it must be wired E-S, B-G, C-D.

I spotted this because it was inserted *backwards* from the silk. Testing it out-of-circuit, sure enough, it is a functional NEMOS.  But what are it's parameters?

Comment: What kind of circuit was it removed from?

Comment: I think as a low-side switch. Scoping around it, it looks like it is for squelching a TTL pulse train to ground, preventing other things from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but I stumbled across this transistor in my own "misc parts" bin. It's a BSS 98, an ancient small-signal N-channel FET.

There's a [datasheet](http://www.elektronikjk.com/elementy_czynne/tranzystory/BSS98.pdf) that specifies the markings as "BSS 98 marked SS98" and [radiomusium](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_bss98.html) has a matching picture of it.

Comment: Were the leads preformed as in the datasheet with the middle lead bent back? That would explain the reverse insertion relative to the silk since D and S on most JFETs are interchangeable.

Comment: No, mine had straight leads as in the first picture of the datasheet.